# Japanese Isekai Novel - Reincarnated protagonist tries to hide his abilities, winds up in rural village, fights werewolf and animal tribes

Tags: story-identification, isekai

Needed help searching for the name of an isekai novel. I have recalled many details, but I just can't remember the novel's name.

1. Mc replaces the memory of his previous owner. If he was known to be reincarnated, he will be known as an apostle of some kind and will be forced to do troublesome stuff, so he purposely lowers his magic power during a magic test, but wasn't able to avoid the troublesome stuff afterwards. He was forced to travel throughout the world, and one man tagged alone with him. A woman later joined him, but she's not a love interest, and the mc thinks that although the male and female companion bickers a lot, they make a good couple. The mc's younger sister was a reincarnated person too, but she's from that isekai world, and she hates heroes for some fcked up reasons heroes did in the past.
2. The title is something along the lines of "I will try to hide my abilities" or something like that.
3. After returning, mc convinces his parents that he's mediocre, and tries to persuade them to let him have a slow life in the barren countryside.
4. Originally, the rural village only have some villagers, few knights and mc. The first enemy was a werewolf, but the mc managed to convince them to move to the village. One of the first few enemies in the arc was the tiger tribe, then the cat tribe. Bird people attacked his village at one point too, but they were rendered flightless after mc uses glass breaking sound, so much it scares the bird-people to be unable to fly. After some time, It turns out, one of the masterminds is an old lady, and she was forced out after the mc and his men used some boars to cause an epidemic and crop destruction.

Just can't recall the novel name despite remembering so much stuff.

Comment: Did you read this in Japanese, or in translation? Can you remember when and where you read it, or when it might be from? Was it a light novel or a full novel?

Comment: "I Think I’ll Hide My True Ability to the Last Moment" might be a match. There is a werewolf according to some online searches. Haven't seen the reincarnation aspect yet.

Comment: https://www.scribblehub.com/tag/hiding-true-abilities/ might be useful for searching.

Comment: @Showsni it's a japanese light nove..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is
"[I Reincarnated But Will Try To Live Without Using My Cheat Ability](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-reincarnated-but-will-try-to-live-without-using-my-cheat-ability/)"

> When someone says, “I’ll give you a cheat ability, so just use it”, don’t you feel like not using it?
>
> There is nothing more expensive than free stuff.
>
> It’s not cool to get excited about something you got for free.
>
> In a sense, the protagonist is a reincarnation target, but he perseveres while messing with God’s plans.
>
> God makes a mistake in choosing his reincarnation target, and later learns of it.
>
> He later realizes that it’s not like everyone wants to be strong and not everyone wants to make a harem.
>
> And that he has chosen someone who is more attentive than others and is a real pain in the ass…

I did a search through my brave browser history....

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept by clicking on the check mark. Of course, as a self-answer, you may have to wait until tomorrow, 48 hours after you ask the question. But congrats! I found the answer to a few questions in that way.